# N+1 while enumerating self-referencing records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a pretty basic thing - displaying a tree of categories in topological order and ActiveRecord issues extra query for enumerating each category's children.

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :parent_id

  belongs_to :parent, :class_name => 'Category'
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Category', :foreign_key => 'parent_id'

  def self.in_order
    all = Category.includes(:parent, :children).all  # Three queries as it should be
    root = all.find{|c| c.parent_id == nil}
    queue = [root]
    result = []
    while queue.any?
      current = queue.shift
      result << current
      current.children.each do |child|  # SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = ?
        queue << child
      end
    end
    result
  end
end
```

UPD. As far as I understand what's going here is that when a category is referred as a children of some category it's not the same object as the one in the initial list and so it hasn't it's children loaded. Is there a way to implement desired behavior without resorting to creating extra adjacency list?

UPD2: Here's the manual adjacency list solution. It uses only one query but I'd really like to use something more idiomatic

```
  def self.in_order_manual
    cache = {}
    adj = {}
    root = nil
    all.each do |c| 
      cache[c.id] = c
      if c.parent_id != nil
        (adj[c.parent_id] ||= []) << c.id
      else
        root = c.id
      end
    end

    queue = [root]
    result = []
    while queue.any?
      current = queue.shift
      result << current
      (adj[current] || []).each{|child| queue << child}
    end
    result.map{|id| cache[id]}
  end
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson How to do it with a somewhat limited numbers of queries, obviously.